# Google Maps, Map is loading, but not completely

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a problem with my Android Studio app using Google Maps, the problem being that my map doesn't completely load. I do get the fully loaded world map, but that's as far as it goes.

The functionality of the app itself works great, I am able to type in whatever country/city/address that I want, and stick a marker to that location (Which in my simple mind tells me that I have all the permissions that I require to utilize the functions I want for this application).

I have been browsing for solutions for hours, but everything I have found, I already have enabled and/or working. I use my Samsung Galaxy S7 phone to run my app and have had no problems so far with Android Studio.

I guess this is just a "cosmetic" issue, but still one I would like to solve.

### What I have tried:

- Clearing the cache on my device of, Google Play Services, Google Play Store
- Getting new API keys from google
- Different map layouts MAP_TYPE_NORMAL, MAP_TYPE_HYBRID <- The hyrbid layout does not load **at all**.
- My internet connection, Wifi/Wireless (I have a fast internet connection using either, I doubt that's the problem)

Pictures to better describe what happens:

[Starting the app with custom markers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY0in.png)

[Zooming in.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B58yE.png)

[Final zoom, with markers in the correct spot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrpFX.jpg)

My code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

EditText searchText;
public GoogleMap mMap;
private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15.0f;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


    try {
        if (mMap == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_search);
    init();
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Map is ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

//init the search
public void init()
{
    searchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
            {
                geoLocate();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void geoLocate()
{
    String searchString = searchText.getText().toString();

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this);
    List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try
    {
        list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchString, 1);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(list.size() > 0)
    {
        Address address = list.get(0);
        LatLng position = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title(searchText.getText().toString()));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
    }
}
```

}

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
   
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!--android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />-->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="*Api*" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My google_maps_api.xml file:

```
<resources>

<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">*Api*</string>
</resources>
```

I obviously discluded the API_KEY's with *Api*.

This is my first post on stackoverflow so any feedback regarding the quality of my post is welcome as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you confirm that you have setup you Android Google Maps SDK API Key in the google developer console, If not then please Enable Google Maps Android API in google developer console with your application identifier and SHA1 fingerprint? The map won't show until the key is authorised for the particular debug/production build of your app.

Comment: Hello and thank you for a fast reply! I solved my problem with your help, although what you suggested was not the case. My problem was more embarrasing than I thought, I had the Geocode API key pasted where the SDK API was supposed to be. I never would have though this was the problem since the map found the information of the addresses & displayed the initial large scale map.